# ETag implementation in Angular2

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I try to implement [odata standard](http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/) which uses [ETag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag). I'm stacked with PATCH requests. With each PATCH request I must send etag in header `If-None-Match`. Then in response HTTP status 200 means that change was applied and status 412 means that the underlying data has changed and I must fetch it again and do somehow merge of data from server and current from application. Merge is out of scope for this question.

So far I have the solution more or less working (adding data and etag to cache is in implementation of `get()` method):

```
export const HEADER_ETAG_MATCH = 'If-None-Match';
export const ODATA_ETAG_PROPERTY = '@odata.etag';
export interface CacheRecordStructure {
    etag: string;
    response: Response;
}
export class CachingService {
    cache: { [key: string]: CacheRecordStructure } = {};
    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    patch(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        let stream$ = new Subject<Response>();
        this.http[type](url, body, this.addEtagHeader(url, options)).subscribe(response => {
            if (response.status === 412) {
                delete this.cache[url];
                this.get(url, options).subscribe(response2 => {
                    response2.status = 412;
                    stream$.next(response2);
                });
            } else {
                this.cache[url].etag = response.json()[ODATA_ETAG_PROPERTY];
                this.cache[url].response = response;
                stream$.next(response);
            }
        });
        return stream$.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Question 1: how to tranform this code to Rx-only, without the need to define `stream$` ?

Question 2: I'd like to throw error instead of status 412. With this error I should somehow return new object fetched from server. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minimal-invasive solution could be to use `switchMap`, it could look like this:

```
export const HEADER_ETAG_MATCH = 'If-None-Match';
export const ODATA_ETAG_PROPERTY = '@odata.etag';
export interface CacheRecordStructure {
    etag: string;
    response: Response;
}
export class CachingService {
    cache: { [key: string]: CacheRecordStructure } = {};
    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    patch(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.http[type](url, body, this.addEtagHeader(url, options))
            .switchMap(response => {
                if (response.status === 412) {
                    delete this.cache[url];
                    return this.get(url, options)
                        .switchMap(response2 => {
                            response2.status = 412;
                            return Observable.throw(response2);
                        });
                } else {
                    this.cache[url].etag = response.json()[ODATA_ETAG_PROPERTY];
                    this.cache[url].response = response;
                    return Observable.of(response);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

And then you'd use it like:

```
myCachingService.patch("myurl...", someBody)
    .subscribe(
        response => console.log(response),
        errorWithNewObj => console.error(errorWithNewObj),
        () => console.info("Done!")
    );
```